# Create a query that puts hierarchy levels into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression, hierarchy

I am trying to write a query in mssql that converts below input table into the desired output

I have a table that represents hierarchy by self-referencing using `parent_id` column.

Here is an example of input table that covers my case.

| id | current_level | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Oldest A | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | Oldest B | NULL |
| 3 | 2 | Old A | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | Old B | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | Young A | 3 |
| 6 | 3 | Young B | 4 |
| 7 | 3 | Young C | 4 |
| 8 | 4 | Youngest A | 5 |
| 9 | 4 | Youngest B | 6 |
| 10 | 4 | Youngest C | 7 |
| 11 | 4 | Youngest D | 7 |
| 12 | 4 | Youngest E | 7 |
| 13 | 4 | Youngest F | 7 |

The idea here is to expand this table by adding as many columns as there are levels. In this case we have 4 levels so we want to add 4 new columns to the table.

This is desired output

| id | current_level | name | parent_id | level_1 | level_2 | level_3 | level_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Oldest A | NULL | Oldest A | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | Oldest B | NULL | Oldest B | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 2 | Old A | 1 | Oldest A | Old A | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | 2 | Old B | 2 | Oldest B | Old B | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | 3 | Young A | 3 | Oldest A | Old A | Young A | NULL |
| 6 | 3 | Young B | 4 | Oldest B | Old B | Young B | NULL |
| 7 | 3 | Young C | 4 | Oldest B | Old B | Young C | NULL |
| 8 | 4 | Youngest A | 5 | Oldest A | Old A | Young A | Youngest A |
| 9 | 4 | Youngest B | 6 | Oldest B | Old B | Young B | Youngest B |
| 10 | 4 | Youngest C | 7 | Oldest B | Old B | Young C | Youngest C |
| 11 | 4 | Youngest D | 7 | Oldest B | Old B | Young C | Youngest D |
| 12 | 4 | Youngest E | 7 | Oldest B | Old B | Young C | Youngest E |
| 13 | 4 | Youngest F | 7 | Oldest B | Old B | Young C | Youngest F |

The two main challenges I am facing here:

1. Number of levels can be dynamic, let's say 1-30 (in this example I presented there are only 4 levels but it is possible that input data will have more levels, e.g. 25, so it would be ideal to make this query dynamic for any number of levels, not just 4)
2. On levels 3 and higher we need to look up more than just immediate parent - basically we need to go through the whole lookup chain until we hit root element (`parent_id == null`).

For example, to populate levels for row with `id = 5` I am using logic like this:

- `if column_level > current_level then SET to NULL` => column level_4 = NULL
- `if column_level == current_level then SET to current_level` => column level_3 = Young A
- `if column_level == current_level-1 then SET to parent_level` => column level_2 = Old A
- `if column_level == current_level-2 then SET to parent_of_parent_level` => column level_1 = Oldest A
- we hit root level because we are on level_1 and parent_of_parent_of_parent doesn't exist => row  number 5 is done

lookup chain for row with id=5 `3(parent)->1(parent_of_parent)->NULL`

---

What I tried:

I have tried to approach this with recursive cte but those don't allow to recursively append new columns or at least I couldn't.

I also started thinking about solution in TSQL but no luck either.

Comment: hmmz I need to practice more with recursive CTE's... .  But here is a, not complete, [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/zMT_BvJ9)

Comment: "Number of levels can be dynamic, let's say 1-30" so what do you want the rest of the columns to be? All nulls? Or do you want to somehow dynamically have different amount of columns depending on results?

Comment: @Charlieface in this example number of levels is only 4 but what I meant by 1-30 is that there can be cases where input data has data for 30 levels so query should be able to handle that. That's why it's a little more challenging as query cannot be hardcoded for only 4 levels

Comment: if it is not feasible to make it dynamic for any amount of levels then I can settle for hardcording for 30 levels and leaving irrelevant levels with NULLS but I am still not sure how to handle those lookup chains up to the level1. It wouldn't be as elegant solution as having dynamic number of levels which would be determined by input data but it would be functional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use a recursive CTE for this.** To get the parent levels you just need to concat them together in the recursive part, using either JSON or XML so you can parse it back out as a list.

It's made substantially more difficult by the fact you want them all as separate columns. You need to therefore use a giant `PIVOT` inside an `APPLY` to get all thirty columns (I haven't bothered renaming them, they are all just `1` `2` `3` etc).

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      t.id,
      t.current_level,
      t.name,
      t.parent_id,
      levels = STRING_ESCAPE(t.name, 'json')
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE current_level = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      t.id,
      t.current_level,
      t.name,
      t.parent_id,
      cte.levels + '","' + STRING_ESCAPE(t.name, 'json')
    FROM cte
    JOIN YourTable t ON t.parent_id = cte.id
)
SELECT
  cte.id,
  cte.current_level,
  cte.name,
  cte.parent_id,
  levels.*
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT
          [key] = CAST([key] AS int) + 1,
          value
        FROM OPENJSON('["' + cte.levels + '"]')
    ) o
    PIVOT (
        MAX(value) FOR [key] IN (
          [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30]
        )
    ) p
) levels;
```

If you don't mind just getting one big JSON blob you can remove the `APPLY` and `PIVOT`

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      t.id,
      t.current_level,
      t.name,
      t.parent_id,
      levels = STRING_ESCAPE(t.name, 'json')
    FROM YourTable t
    WHERE current_level = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      t.id,
      t.current_level,
      t.name,
      t.parent_id,
      cte.levels + '","' + STRING_ESCAPE(t.name, 'json')
    FROM cte
    JOIN YourTable t ON t.parent_id = cte.id
)
SELECT
  cte.id,
  cte.current_level,
  cte.name,
  cte.parent_id,
  levels = '["' + cte.levels + '"]'
FROM cte;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/alpaD8y8)